# How can I shift Ext.Window together with its shadow using getEl().shift()?

Tags: extjs

I was trying to do a shift using Ext.Fx on the Ext.Window.

```
text: 'move right',
handler: function() {
startx+=100;
var el = thewindow.getEl();
el.shift({
    x: startx,
    });
}
```

What happen was, the window shift but the shadow didn't... Any idea?

Cheers,
Mickey

Comment: I don't use Ext.Fx, but if you post a more complete working example, I could try to play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to test it at my current location, but quick quess would be that you have to call something like the method `syncShadow()`. It is similar to when you are using `autoHeight` on a window and the window size changes, but not the shadow.

Comment: I tried, but it doesnt seems to have any effect, maybe I didnt do it right. let me know if it works for you. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

What browser?  Just tested shifting a window in both FF and Safari and it worked fine.

On a side note, I assume that `startx` is initially defined somewhere properly before you start incrementing it?

Comment: I simply modified one of the existing Ext window examples and added win.getEl().shift({x:100});  Worked fine.